# Delta-update Firefox Aurora package from PPA

Tags: updates, firefox, package-management, ppa, dpkg

I am using Firefox Aurora in my Ubuntu 12.04 which I have installed via its ppa (`ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora`). As expected of Aurora, I get an update usually after 2-3 days. I have Firefox Aurora installed in Windows too. There also I get updates in 2-3 days but size of update is usually 4-5 MB, while in Ubuntu it's always around 20 MB.
What is the reason for this difference? Is there any way by which I can download and install only the *changes* and not the entire Aurora again and again?

Comment: The only way I know of currently to get delta updates is to install Aurora direct from [Mozilla](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/). There will possibly be disadvantages such as lack of "integration" and having to set up an AppArmor profile. But you will get the delta updates, mostly everyday, via Mozilla's internal updater. Sometimes, there's an intraday respin of builds and then you may get a "full" update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not currently support updating a package using deltas. The dpkg format Ubuntu usage *does* support delta packages, but the higher-level tools like APT apparently still don't.

- According to [When will Ubuntu include delta updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10167/when-will-ubuntu-include-delta-updates), this feature has been under discussion since 2009, but not actually finished. The relevant blueprints are:

  - https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-o-debdelta/ / https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDebdeltaSupport
  - Related: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/foundations-m-rsync-based-deb-downloads
- The corresponding feature in Fedora is called [Presto](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Presto).