# Are delta updates going to appear in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will Ubuntu include delta updates?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10167/when-will-ubuntu-include-delta-updates)

There are a few giant packages on my machine (games of several gigabytes). When they get an update, I have to re-download the whole package.

It would be great I only the changes got pushed between updates. Is this kind of delta updating coming to Ubuntu?